# ASP Core 2 Как получить имя пользователя, который зашел на сайт?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Как мне получить имя пользователя, который зашел на сайт, без каких либо аутентификаций, нужно только имя. Сайт будет находиться внутри сети кампании.

Все сотрудники уже изначально проходят авторизацию виндовс, после чего спокойно работают в интернете. Я знаю, что у того же asp.net имеется windows авторизация, которая подтягивает данные пользователя.

Но выбор был на ASP Core, ибо будет сервер на линукс... Исходя из этого, нам достаточно получить имя пользователя windows, чтобы без авторизации в AD его выводить на сайт. Но как это сделать, не ясно.

Comment: чтобы получить имя, нужно как то залогинить...иначе можно попробоват ьполучить разве что `ip`. Не совсем понятна суть задачи...опишите конечную цель

Comment: более подробно описал проблему

Comment: посмотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49682644/asp-net-core-2-0-ldap-active-directory-authentication) вопрос

Comment: тут происходит авторизация по логину-пароль, но мне нужно только имя пользователя, который зашел на сайт